# fs.writeFile not saving even when path is correct

Tags: node.js, windows, xampp, fs

Having an issue with fs.writeFile in my nodejs app running locally where im getting an error of this below,
I am running on localhost xampp also on windows if that may be an issue?

```html
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\exampleuser\Desktop\examplenodejspath\product\sku123.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\Desktop\\examplenodejspath\\product\\sku123.json'
}
```

Below is a copy of the code.

```js
var product = {"SKU": "sku123","name": "test"};

fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/product/" + product.SKU + ".json", product, 'utf8', function (err) {

        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("product was saved!");
});
```

I can confirm the path is correct. but for some reason it still returns its not correct.

Any help would be appericated

Comment: What does it mean "running on localhost through xampp on windows"?  It seems you likely either have a path problem or a permissions problem for the process trying to run this code.   Are you 100% sure that the nodejs code has permission to access this user's directory?

Comment: Im running Nodejs locally on my machine.
the machine is windows platform

Im using xampp for other functions. i just figured it could be an issue

Comment: Did you make the directory `C:\\Users\\exampleuser\\Desktop\\examplenodejspath\\product` at first?

Comment: Does it work any better if you try `fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, path.sep, "/product/", path.sep, product.SKU, path.sep, ".json",.......`  with `require('path')`;

Comment: @Mark - May as well just use `path.join()` rather than that.  Anyway, you can see the actual path in the error report and it seems as expected (for a path on Windows).

Comment: @jfriend00 brain fart (i did use `path.join()` though)  Try 
 `fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "product", product.SKU + ".json",.....) `  Easy thing to try.   It's late...

Comment: To repeat @lx1412's question: did you remember to ensure the _directory_ you're writing to exists? Because Node doesn't just make dirs for you: if it's not there, your filewrite will fail, and you probably want to install `fs-extra` and call its `ensureDir` before you do your filewrite.